# What is the flower-like motif appearing right on top of the arches of structures built by Qutb Shahi dynasty?

Tags: identification, india, architecture, mughals

This floral motif could be found on almost every structure built by the Qutub Shahi dynasty/ the Deccan Sultanate.

Below image is from Charminar, Hyderabad.

[image: Floral structure found on Charminar]

Similar motifs on Qutb Shahi Tombs:

[image: Same structures on the Qutb Shahi Tombs]

One could also see this on [Gol Gumbaz](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gol_Gumbaz,_Bijapur,_Karnataka_-2.jpg) and even on [Gandikota Fort entrance](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Gandikota_Fort_Entrance.jpg).
What exactly is this symbol and what does it represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those flowers likely represent lotus.

This is from the [Charminar Wikipedia page - the German edition](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charminar#Architektur):
[image]

Simple translation: "[...] These end in Chhatris with bellied domes, which in turn rest in wide-open stone lotus flowers"

Now, this refers to the flowers next to the closed ones (in your upper picture) but it can be assumed that the middle ones topping the arches are thereby closed ones.

Closed lotus flowers look like this:
[image]

This [UNESCO description of the Charminar](https://whc.unesco.org/en/tentativelists/5573/) seems to confirm the lotus hypothesis

> "The Charminar's ground storey is indeed capped by a low compressed
> dome adorned with a solar lotus at its apex."

Comment: Thanks, that's likely the explanation.